# Adding two where conditions in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I know to check how to fetch a particular item in laravel like

```
$PackCount = PackModel::where('PackId', Input::get('packid'))->count();
```

But how can i check whether the items are matches another two coloumn i.e.,

where condition for IsActive and IsAvailable ?

Comment: Please provide some more description regarding DB table details and what exactly you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have more `where` in your Query then just do

```
$PackCount = PackModel::where('PackId', Input::get('packid'))->where('IsActive', '=', '1')->where('IsAvailable', '=', '1')->count();
```

Read more about [Advance Where here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$count = PackModel::where('PackId', Input::get('packid'))->where('IsActive',  '1')->where('IsAvailable', '1')->count();
```